# Why doesn't "echo" show up in "ps"?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ps

I am having great difficulty in understanding what shows up on ps command. To test my understanding I created below dummy script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for i in {1..100000}
 do
  date -u
  date -u
  date -u
 done
```

while running this script I opened a new terminal and executed repeatedly

```
ps -eaf | grep date | grep -v grep
```

and I was able to date process in the output.

I later changed dummy script by replacing `date -u` with `echo "what is going on"`

```
     #!/bin/bash
     for i in {1..100000}
     do
      echo "What is going on"
      echo "What is going on"
      echo "What is going on"
     done
```

while running the updated dummy script, I opened a new terminal and executed repeatedly

```
ps -eaf | grep echo | grep -v grep
```

and echo was never shown in output. Why is this? I suspect the reason is the script being a bash script, may be it is using builtin echo therefore it was not displayed in ps output. Am I correct? What am I missing here?

Comment: As you surmise, `echo` isn't a process. It's a shell built-in command.

Comment: Original title was *extremely* vague -- and also something that couldn't be straightforwardly answered in a cross-platform way (POSIX's specification for ps output format leaves much to the individual implementation, unless one is assured of XSI compliance).

Comment: @lurker Not necessarily.  A lot of people think `bash` is the world's only shell.  It is built into `bash`, `zsh` and a bunch of others.  It is decidedly not built-in to `sh`, the Bourne shell.  And there is indeed a `/bin/echo` executable in coreutils.

Comment: ...though many POSIX sh implementations *do* build in `echo`.

Comment: BTW, what's the real-world problem you're trying to solve? Is this is for purposes of locking, or for ensuring a single process instance, `ps` is **absolutely** the wrong tool for the job (see `flock`).

Comment: It's not part of the spec, though.  And a lot of Linuxen link `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: (also, insert here some grumbling about conflating POSIX sh with Bourne -- the latter being born about 20 years prior to the former).

Comment: @TrippKinetics yes that's true, and I know `bash` isn't *the world's only shell*. But the OP indicated `bash` in their tags, so I just naturally assumed that's what they are using.

Comment: Well, there's also weirdness like in my own default shell, I've bypassed some of the shell built-ins with aliases, but that's really outside the scope of the question...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I need to echo password to curl -K, so that password can be read from stdin and not displayed in ps

Comment: If you'd asked whether a given practice for calling `curl` was secure, frankly, that would have been a more sensible question. Easier to answer in a cross-platform manner, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`echo` is a builtin in bash:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

That means that a new process is not created when `echo` is run. All the work is done by the `bash` process instead, which is way more efficient.

You can run the non-builtin `echo` explicitly:

```
command echo "What is going on"
```

This forks and execs `/bin/echo` instead, letting it show up in `ps`.