# automated mongodump: how to hide password from ps output?

Tags: mongodb, security, passwords, mongodump

okay so we we have the **mongodump** tool, it has --password option. Everything works great except this plain password is visible in ps output to everybody.

our database has plain user/password authentication.

The only thing that I found to work is doing like this

```
echo secretpwd |  mongodump --username backup --oplog
```

no trace of password in ps and still working.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--password):

> Changed in version 3.0.2: If you wish mongodump to prompt the user for
>   the password, pass the --username option without --password or specify
>   an empty string as the --password value, as in --password "" .

Seems like what you are doing is the recommended way.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831457/1100528) can help further:

> If the secret doesn't change between executions, use a special
>   configuration file, ".appsecrets". Set the permissions of the file to
>   be read-only by owner. Inside the file set an environment variable to
>   the secret. The file needs to be in the home directory of the user
>   running the command.

Comment: looks ugly anyway. Maybe it'd be slighly less ugly if we do it like cat /home/password.txt | mongodump .... Does echo show up in process list by the way? I think it does.

Comment: Haha I just added a reference to something similar from another thread.

Comment: Oh and echo doesn't show up because it doesn't spawn a new process in bash. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840191/why-doesnt-echo-show-up-in-ps) out.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but it looks like recent versions of `mongodump` do explicitly support reading the password from standard in. I didn't see anything about it in the documentation, but when I use a similar command to the one in the OP, `mongodump` generates output like:

```
reading password from standard input
```

I'm not sure if it's any better than using echo like in the OP, but I store the password in a file and then use it like this: `mongodb --username backup < /path/to/password.txt`