# How to use sudo programmatically via a pipe?

Tags: ruby, ssh, sudo, tty

I am trying to write a program to perform remote administration of a system. To this end, I issue SSH commands and provide input programmatically via a pipe. I also capture their output.

Some of the commands require elevation, so I need to issue commands such as `ssh user@host "sudo apt-get install blah"`.

The problem is, `sudo` refuses point-blank to accept a password via the terminal unless it finds a *real terminal* on its stdin. Is there some way I can fool `sudo` into allowing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proper way to sudo over ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S command
```

-S accepts password from stdin

Comment: Well, that was easier than I expected.

Comment: @SodAlmighty - you might have a look at the link in Kenster's second comment for a discussion of security concerns(in the comments).