# Python: How to execute a program over SSH that requires `sudo`

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to run a deamon over a remote Linux machine, using SSH.

Deamon's name is `pigpiod` and it belongs to `pigpio` module ( controling Raspberry Pi's GPIO ), Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Executing commands that does not require `sudo` (for example- `ls`)- script runs OK, while those who need `sudo`, fails.

adress='192.168.2.112' , is a remote Linux to run this daemon.

> Code below fails (running `sudo pigpiod`):

```
def runpigpiod_remote(adress):
    result = subprocess.run(['ssh','guy@'+adress,'sudo','pigpiod'])
```

> Code below succeeds(run `ls -l`)

```
def runpigpiod_remote(adress):
    result = subprocess.run(['ssh','guy@'+adress,'ls','-l'])
```

In order the check if `subprocess.run` capable of executing sudo+ command - I tryied localy on same machine and it succeeds:

```
def run_process():
    try:
        check_output(["pidof","pigpiod"])
        print("pigpiod already loaded")
    except:
        subprocess.CalledProcessError
        print("Not Loaded")
        subprocess.run(['sudo','pigpiod'])
        if os.system("pgrep -x "+name)==0:
            print("Loaded successfully")
```

Comment: can you do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh

Comment: **yes** thanks to the `sudo -t` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code changed ( thanks to comment of @Hamuel )- as noted in [proper way to sudo over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh)

```
def runpigpiod_remote(adress):
    result = subprocess.run(['ssh','-t','guy@'+adress,'sudo','pigpiod'])
```