# Execute a sudo command through SSH on a remote server using Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, nginx, ssh

I am trying to use a .sh script on Windows 10 (through Git Bash) to restart my nginx server.

This is what I'm trying

```
$ ssh myname@myserver 'sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload'
sudo: Command not found.
```

I'm not sure why this happens, I know `sudo` isn't defined in Git Bash but shouldn't the command execute on the server? When I `ssh` in manually and run the same command it works:

```
$ ssh myname@myserver
$ myserver:/home/myname[ 51 ] --> sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
Password:
```

Comment: Try providing the full path to `sudo`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh

Comment: Which OS is the server running?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon That worked, thanks a lot! I also had to add -t, so the final line was `ssh myname@myserver -t '/tool/sysadmin/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload'`. The server OS was RHEL 7